# How to make function execute faster in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, database-performance

I am using function to update to one column , like

```
DetailedStatus = dbo.fn_GetProcessStageWiseStatus(PR.ProcessID, PR.ProcessRunID, getdate())
```

Here 500,000 records are continuously UPDATED in this line. Its like like a loop

So using this function for few records its executing fast but when its 500,000 records executing it becomes very slow...

What can I do to make this execute faster using many records?

Any measures to be taken or any split to be used?

**Function:**

```
             CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetProcessStageWiseStatus]    
       (    
       @ProcessID INT    
        ,@ProcessRunID INT    
        ,@SearchDate SMALLDATETIME    
       )    
          RETURNS VARCHAR(100)    
         AS    

      BEGIN    
         DECLARE      
             @iLoopCount SMALLINT    
            ,@iRowCount SMALLINT    
            ,@StepProgress VARCHAR(100)    
            ,@StepCount SMALLINT    

     IF EXISTS(    
              SELECT TOP 1 1    
              FROM dbo.Step S WITH(NOLOCK)    
              JOIN dbo.vw_FileGroup FG    
                    ON S.FileConfigGroupID = FG.FileConfigGroupID    
              WHERE S.ProcessID = @ProcessID    
              AND S.Active = 1    
              AND FG.FileConfigGroupActive = 1    
              AND FG.Direction = 'Inbound'    
              )    
  BEGIN    
        SET @StepProgress = 'Not Received'    
  END    
  ELSE    
  BEGIN    
        SET @StepProgress = 'Not Started'    
  END    

  DECLARE @StepRunDetailsTable TABLE    
  (    
        KeyNo INT IDENTITY(1,1)    
        ,StepID INT    
        ,StepStartTime SMALLDATETIME    
        ,StepEndTime SMALLDATETIME    
        ,SourceEnv VARCHAR(100)    
        ,DestEnv VARCHAR(100)    
  )    

  INSERT INTO @StepRunDetailsTable     
  SELECT    
        S.StepID    
        ,MAX(isnull(SR.StepStartTime, '06/06/2079'))    
        ,MAX(isnull(SR.StepEndTime, '06/06/2079'))    
        ,isnull(SENV.EnvironmentName, '')    
        ,isnull(DENV.EnvironmentName, '')    
  FROM dbo.ProcessRun PR WITH(NOLOCK)    
  JOIN dbo.StepRun SR WITH(NOLOCK)    
        ON SR.ProcessRunID = PR.ProcessRunID    
  JOIN dbo.vw_StepHierarchy SH    
        ON SR.StepID = SH.StepID    
        AND SH.Active = 1    
  JOIN dbo.Step S WITH(NOLOCK)    
        ON SH.StepID = S.StepID    
  JOIN dbo.WorkFlow WF WITH(NOLOCK)    
        ON S.WorkFlowID = WF.WorkFlowID    
        AND WF.Active = 1           
  JOIN dbo.Environment SENV WITH(NOLOCK)    
        ON SENV.EnvironmentID = WF.SourceEnvironmentID    
        AND SENV.Active = 1               
  JOIN dbo.Environment DENV WITH(NOLOCK)    
        ON DENV.EnvironmentID = WF.DestinationEnvironmentID    
        AND DENV.Active = 1    
  WHERE PR.ProcessRunID = @ProcessRunID    
  GROUP BY S.StepID, SENV.EnvironmentName, DENV.EnvironmentName, SH.StepOrder    
  ORDER BY SH.StepOrder ASC    

  SELECT @StepCount = COUNT(*)    
  FROM dbo.ProcessRun PR WITH(NOLOCK)    
  JOIN dbo.Step S WITH(NOLOCK)    
        ON PR.ProcessID = S.ProcessID    
        AND PR.ProcessRunID = @ProcessRunID    
        AND S.Active = 1    

  SELECT @iRowCount = COUNT(DISTINCT StepID) FROM @StepRunDetailsTable    

  SET @iLoopCount = 0      

  WHILE (@iRowCount > @iLoopCount)      
  BEGIN      
        SET @iLoopCount = @iLoopCount + 1    

        SELECT    
              @StepProgress =     
                    CASE    
                          --WHEN @SearchDate BETWEEN StepStartTime AND StepEndTime     
                          WHEN @SearchDate >= StepStartTime AND  @SearchDate <= StepEndTime     
                                THEN DestEnv + ' Load in Progress'    
                          WHEN @SearchDate > StepEndTime AND @iLoopCount < @StepCount    
                                THEN 'Waiting on next step - Loaded to ' + DestEnv    
                          WHEN @SearchDate > StepEndTime AND @iLoopCount = @StepCount    
                                THEN 'Completed'    
                          WHEN @SearchDate < StepStartTime AND @iLoopCount = 1    
                                THEN 'Load Not Started'    
                          ELSE @StepProgress    
              END    

        FROM @StepRunDetailsTable    
        WHERE KeyNo = @iLoopCount    
  END    

  RETURN @StepProgress
```

END

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what that function does! Show us the code!

Comment: Can you please check edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a change in execution plan when you try to update 500k rows. 
You can try and set `forceseek` hint on the `from` clause to force using seeks instead of scans.

Also, `WHILE (@iRowCount > @iLoopCount)` should be replaced with `if exists`, because you basically check for certain conditions on the results table and you need to return as early as possible.

I see that you use `nolock` hint everywhere to allow dirty reads, you can `set isolation level read uncommitted` in the calling stored procedure and remove all of those; or consider to change the database to `set read_committed_snapshot on` to avoid locks.

By the way, scalar function calls in SQL Server are very expensive, so if you have some massive updates/selects happening in a loop where you call a function you have to avoid using functions as much as possible.

Comment: Instead of functions what whould you suggest to use?

Comment: @Pink put all that code in a stored procedure; yes, that's a breach of  the DRY and KISS principles. Re-think all that code in terms of set-based operations, currently you're doing everything on a row basis, piece-wise.